# First order equation with one unknown variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Problem Given:** Twelve years ago the age of $A$ was the double of age of $B$ and in the next twelve years, the age of $A$ would be $68$ years less than triple of $B$. Find the current ages.

What I've done is set up the equations

$$2x-12=3(x+12)-68+12$$

where $2x-12$ is the age of $A$, $3(x+12)$ is the triple of age of $B$ in the future $(+12)$. And the last $12$ because in the sentence says 'is in the next twelve years.'

But the answer doesn't match with the solution on the book $A=52$ and $B=32$.

Could someone tell how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for some reason no one felt the need to elaborate on where these equations came from, much less OP's error, I'll do it then.

Though a word of import -- To note for future reference, OP, showing your process might help because otherwise no one can really understand where your own errors come from without it. I happened on your error by simply working the problem the same by mere coincidence; these problems can be solved many different ways, so it's merely luck we coincided.

I'm going to start from the beginning.

---

> Twelve years ago the age of A was the double of age of B and in the next twelve years, the age of A would be 68 years less than triple of B. Find the current ages.

Let $A,B$ denote the respective persons' ages. Then, since "Twelve years ago the age of A was the double of age of B," we know

$$A - 12 =2(B - 12) = 2B - 24 $$

Similarly, per "in the next twelve years, the age of A would be 68 years less than triple of B," we know

$$A + 12 = 3(B+12) - 68 = 3B + 36 - 68 = 3B - 32$$

This gives us a system of equations:

$$A - 12 = 2B - 24$$
$$A + 12 = 3B - 32$$

Equivalently, since $A$ seems easiest to solve for,

$$A = 2B - 12 = 3B - 44$$

Thus, we have the equation in $B$, for which we solve:

$$2B - 12 = 3B - 44 \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; B = 32$$

Plug $B = 32$ into any equation of our system of equations, and you'll find $A = 52$.

---

As for where your error lies, OP, it's this:

> What I've done is
>   $$2x-12=3(x+12)-68+12$$ where
>   $2x-12$ is the age of $A$, $3(x+12)$ is the triple of age of $B$ in the future $(+12)$. And the last $12$ because in the sentence says 'is in the next twelve years.'

That last $+12$ is unnecessary. Yes, it is in $12$ years from the present, but that $12$ years is meant to turn $x$ into $x+12$ (as you already have done in parentheses). Since, at that $12$-year-mark, the "$68$ less than the triple" relation is satisfied, you do not add a further $12$.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Twelve years ago the age of A was the double of age of B so .........$$A-12 = 2(B - 12)$$

$$2B - A = 12 \tag{1}$$

In the next twelve years, the age of A would be 68 years less than triple of B so ......$$3(B + 12) - (A + 12) = 68$$

$$3B - A = 44 \tag{2}$$

Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$:

$$B = 32$$

Then $$A = 52$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your attempted solution is you are using one unknown $x$ for two people. You must use two unknowns for two people.

You can organize all in table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
&12 \ \text{years ago}&Now& 12 \ \text{year after}\\
\hline
Adam&A-12&A&A+12\\
Beth&B-12&B&B+12\\
\hline
Conditions&A-12=2(B-12)&&A+12=3(B+12)-68\end{array}.$$
Can you solve the system of two equations and find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very clear.